# acts_as_commentable can I create without updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-commentable

The current controller code I'm using to create a comment on a Post object is this:

```
    commentable = @post
    comment = commentable.comments.create
    # comment.title = params[:title] #Title not needed
    comment.comment = params[:comment][:comment]
    comment.user = current_user

    gon.post_id = @post.id #for javascript

    if comment.save
    ....
```

This is also how it's recommended on the docs.

Is there a way to do this by passing the params into the .create function, like

```
(user = current_user ....)
```

This avoid making 2 calls to the db on a create, thus upping performance.

Additionally, if you're using the public_activity gem it makes things easier too. because it adds a Created and Updated activity on my database every time I write a comment.

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

more simpler approach to include commentable model in your rails app..[Railscasts for adding commentable](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Comment: While adding a commentable model isn't too difficult. I disagree that it's simpler than using the gem; provided I can build a comment in one db query.

Comment: @DavidSigley  but your code will increase when there will be multiple comments with reply from multiple users for multiple models having commentable

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you think it would increase? I'm already using multiple models, but I still don't think my code will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it was actually really simple.

```
 comment = commentable.comments.create(:comment => params[:comment], :user => current_user)
```

Add :title if you're using that feature.

I don't understand why this isn't the solution provided in the docs? I should probably modify it to use

```
create(comment_params)
```